# Windows 7 stereomix

Tags: stereo

How can I download or turn on my *stereo mix* feature in Windows 7? In music chat rooms I can't play music. When I had Windows XP, I had the *stereo mix* option in Audio settings. I can't seem to find it here.

Answer (score 1):

It's a driver's feature. Update your sound card driver, if it won't appear then your sound card just doesn't provide Stereo Mix feature.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the audio / sound icon close to your time and calender in the bottom right corner. Right click and navigate to recording devices.

In this windows, right-click on a blank area, and check that View Disabled Devices and View Disconnected Devices options are checked. You should see the stereo mix appear.

Right click on the stereo mix and select enable. Also, you could set it as default should you rarely make use of the mic.